# Interpret trace from Tensorflow run

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, trace

I would like to profile my neural network architecture in Tensorflow because my GPU usage is only around 50%. To do so, I followed this: [explanation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-225754659).

I obtained a JSON trace of my architecture. To open it, I used chrome://tracing/.

The results I got were these: [timeline.json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-RgwP79IdoDUXdqcWJBaDFlckU). Unfortunately, I didn't know how to interpret them. Any tips on how to interpret such a trace would be much appreciated.

This is a screenshot of my timeline:

[image]